# Why jgit set core.fileMode to false by default

Tags: jgit

Why:

```
val git = Git
  .cloneRepository()
  .setURI(s"https://github.com/whatever/whatever.git")
  .call()

println(git.getRepository.getConfig.getBoolean("core", "fileMode", true))
// Prints false
```

Whereas if I read the documentation:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corefileMode

> The default is true (when core.filemode is not specified in the config file).

So why JGit decide for me to override core.filemode?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

JGit sets the filemode differently on windows and unix-like operating systems. Since windows does not have an executable bit the default is false here.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I opened an issue:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519887

And provided a fix:
https://git.eclipse.org/r/101582